# How can I compare guns in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

My problem is that I keep unlocking new weapons and I really don't understand a great way to compare the guns.  I understand that if I start with a new weapon I need to spend a lot of time to unlock the good unlocks for that weapon, but there must be some general consensus as to some top guns and attachments.

Comment: What I find in most of these "realistic shooter" games is that the guns are all pretty similar - in real life, if you point an assault rifle and someone else and fire it, they die.  Who made it, the specific type of round that it fires, or what factory line it came off of tend not to make that much of a difference ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Weapon comparison charts:

http://denkirson.xanga.com/756891604/bf3/

http://symthic.com/?s=bf3

Each site has forums with more discussions on the subject.

There really isn't a "best gun", it depends on your play style, your class and in the end what you are comfortable playing with.