# Comparison JNG-90 vs m98b vs M40A5 sniper bf3

Tags: battlefield-3

How do these 3 sniping rifles compare in accuracy, damage, reloading speed, bulletdrop, rounds per magazine,...?

Comment: Your question is a subset of this one: [How can I compare guns in BF3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47774/how-can-i-compare-guns-in-bf3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNG-90

- Damage: 80-59 points
- Reload Speed: 2.5 seconds loaded, 4.5 seconds empty
- Ammo capacity: 10 + 1
- Max Ammo: 66 + 11
- RPM: 46.2
- Max Rage: 2,800M

M98b

- Damage: 95 - 59
- Reload Speed: 2.9 seconds loaded, 4.7 seconds empty
- Ammo capacity: 5 + 1 rounds
- Max Ammo: 60 + 6 rounds
- RPM: 46.15

M40A5

- Damage: 80 - 59
- Reload Speed: 2.7 seconds loaded, 4 seconds empty
- Ammo capacity: 10 + 1 rounds
- Max Ammo: 55 + 11 rounds
- RPM: 54.5 RPM

All are bolt-action sniper rifles. The M98b does a higher damage-per-shot rate but has a much smaller magazine and longer reload time.

All info from the Battlefield 3 Wiki. [Symthic.com](http://symthic.com/bf3-weapon-charts?recon=1&sort=Class&adsc=DESC&attc=None) has a excellent comparison tool for looking at different weapons.